# html page not rendering in firefox using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

after surfing for more than 2 hours and couldn't achieve the goal finally decided to paste the problem here , the problem i am facing that is cross browsing problem , the html document which i am rendering through angular js working fine in chrome and safari but firefox is not showing any thing i am sharing my route code

```
var postModule = angular.module('postingModules',['postingControllers']);

postModule.config(function($routeProvider)
 {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/', {

            controller      :   'postingContOnLoad',
            templateUrl     :   '/angularpostform.html'
        })
        .when('/demo',{
            controller      :  'postingContOnLoad',
            templateUrl     :  '/views/testingDemo.html'
        })

        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

});
```

and the div in which the html document is rendering

```
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

The output of chrome and safari browser.

```
<div data-ng-view=""><form class="form-horizontal ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" name="doBoxForm" id="dobox-form">WHOLE CONTENT</form></div>
```

Where as for Firefox:

```
<div data-ng-view=""></div> //Empty div nothing inside
```

Comment: create a demo in plunker that replicates problem....make sure all your html is valid

Comment: also inspect template ajax requests in firebug to see status. Are any errors thrown?

Comment: @chliettfl no error has been thrown by firebug

Comment: what about the ajax requests? are they being made?

Comment: there is no ajax requests involved

Comment: are templates cached then? If not they are pulled from server using ajax. WHere's the demo ? Can set it up simply in plunker

Comment: ok here is my code in plunker but though its working properly

Comment: plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/qLmSu0IF3BAmDpeAwLQZ?p=preview)

Comment: what is that demo supposed to show? There is no `ng-view` in the html

Comment: how does it do in other browsers like chrome, or safari?